# PowerShell, tell a script to output all errors to a text file

Tags: powershell, error-handling, runtime-error

I have a PowerShell script that is the startup script for Windows Sandbox and so it runs silently.

Is it possible to put some kind of declaration within a PowerShell script, say at the start of the script, that tells the silently running script to output all of its errors to a text file?

Edit (for Fitzgery's comment): it is not possible for me to use redirection for the script because it is running silently as part of the Windows Sandbox startup. I would like something within the script itself to instruct the running script to output all errors to a text file.

Comment: Have you looked into the ``redirection`` operator https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: *because mobile doesnt want to cooperate. If you’re calling your script from the powershell console you can try adding ``2>> $outfile`` and see if that works for you

Comment: That's the specific issue, I can't call it from the console in that way, it is sucked in by the `.wsb`, so it runs in a hidden way. This is desireable, I want it to be silent, but it would be etremely useful to be able to see any errors that may be generated. I would gladly use redirection if possible and do that often with other scripts, but it is not possible here.

Comment: like, wrapping all your script in a `try` block and then in the `catch` block you capture the error `$_` and output it to a file?

Comment: Even when running silently there will be information and error channels. Not just a visible console, right? Did you try the redirect options? Then there is always `Start-Transcript` that will give you everything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, which relies on the fact that all errors that occur in a session get recorded in the **[automatic `$Error` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#error)**:

```bash
$Error.Clear() # Reset the session's error log so far

try {

  # ... your script

} finally {
  # Save all errors that occurred in this script to a file.
  $Error > errors.txt
}
```

**Caveat**:

- The use of a [`try`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement has a **side effect**:

  - **Your script may terminate *prematurely***, because **any normally only *statement*-terminating error becomes a *script*-terminating error and therefore instantly triggers the `finally` clause**; that said, ***statement*-terminating errors aren't common**, and it's arguably *better* to abort execution when they occur (unanticipated).
- If you were to *omit* the `try` statement and simply placed `$Error > errors.txt` at the end of your script, (*non-terminating* and) *statement*-terminating errors would be handled as usual, but the `$Error > errors.txt` statement would never get to execute if a *script*-terminating error occurred.

---

An **alternative solution using [`trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap)** is **side effect-free**  ***only* if you know your script *not* to produce *script*-terminating errors**:

- *Script*-terminating errors are those *explicitly* created with [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Throw), or *implicitly* via `-ErrorAction Stop` or `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`
- The (rarely used anymore) [`trap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Trap)
  statement allows you to act on errors *without stopping execution*, namely if you do *not* use `break` in the script block you pass to it.

  - While it therefore continues after *non-terminating* and *statement*-terminating errors, as during normal execution, it also continues after *script*-terminating ones.
  - Therefore, the **side effect - if you script *does* create *script*-terminating errors**, is that it **may not stop your script when you expect it to**.

```bash
# Create or truncate the target file.
$errLogFile = New-Item errors.txt -Force

# Traps all errors and logs them in the target ffile.
# Note:
#  * Using neither `break` or `continue` in the script block
#    still also prints the error and continues execution.
#  * CAVEAT: Even *script*-terminating errors then
#            do NOT abort execution.
trap { $_ >> $errLogFile }

# ... your script
```

---

**Use of [`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript)**:

- `Start-Transcript` is an **way to capture *all* of a script's output, not just *errors*** (that is, output from *all* of PowerShell's [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) is logged, **notably including *success* output (data)** - **you get no choice**).
- It must be paired with [`Stop-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/stop-transcript) to close the transcript file.

  - **If you neglect to call `Stop-Transcript`, the transcript stays open and *continues logging* for the remainder of the session**.
  - In order **to *ensure* that `Stop-Transcript` is called**, you're faced with the **same tradeoffs as above**:

    - Calling it in the `finally` block of a `try` statement may abort execution prematurely.
    - Use of a `trap` statement without `break` may not stop execution when it should.
  - That said, **if the execution of your script is the *only* thing happens in your session** - such as in a CLI call with `-File` - ***not* calling `Stop-Transcript` won't be a problem**, and ensures side effect-free logging - albeit invariably including *all* of the script's output, as noted.